# ' jps' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: hadoop-plugins

jps' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file error while installing Hadoop file distribution system ..this is the error Which I was getting while setting up the Hadoop distributed file system in my laptop